# simple webservice that takes and image and stores it in a folder on the server

Tags: php

As you know the following code snippet is the simplest one for PHP to upload a file and stores it on the server:

```
 <?php
 $uploaddir = "uploads/";
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Success";
} else {
echo "Failure";
}
?>
```

I want the same functionality of this code snippet written as a web service (so that clients can call it with one parameter that is the file to be uploaded and let's say it will be an image).

thank you in advance.

Comment: i want to wrap this code to be used as a web service

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES is a special case for `<input type="file">` elements of forms.  Web services usually use XML or JSON data. The client will have to include the image file contents directly in the data. If you use JSON, your PHP can use `json_decode` to parse the input, then just open the upload file and write the data to it.